# Rebus with Dracula

Tags: rebus

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
    0123 56789 DRACULA
```

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's got to be:

> "out 4 + the Count" = **"to be out for the count."**

Comment: how does the dracula part make sense then?

Comment: @TheDragonista Count Dracula

Comment: My thought had been "out for blood", but this makes more sense.