# My third Rebus puzzle

Tags: english, rebus

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
      L
      D
    BRIDGE
```

See also 
([Rebus with Dracula](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8709/rebus-with-dracula))  and 
([Another Rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/another-rebus-puzzle))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I love rebus puzzles! That one is perhaps somewhat on the easy side:

> "L on D on BRIDGE" = **"London Bridge"**