# My fourth Rebus puzzle

Tags: english, rebus

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
    J O K E
       U
```

See also 
([Rebus with Dracula](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8709/rebus-with-dracula))  and 
([Another Rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/another-rebus-puzzle)) and
([My third Rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/my-third-rebus-puzzle))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the answer to this puzzle is

> The joke is on you