# One Another - Rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus, english

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
   ONE ANOTHER
   ONE ANOTHER
   ONE ANOTHER
   ONE ANOTHER
   ONE ANOTHER
   ONE ANOTHER
```

See also 
([Rebus with Dracula](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8709/rebus-with-dracula))  and 
([Another Rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/another-rebus-puzzle)) and
([My third Rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/my-third-rebus-puzzle)) and
([My fourth Rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8903/my-fourth-rebus-puzzle))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That one must be

> "Six times ONE + six times ANOTHER" = **"Six of one, half a dozen of another"**.